# I can't define functions in Octave

Tags: function, octave

It says that 'x' is not defined and I don't know what to do about it since 'x' is supposed to be an user-defined variable.

I'm new to coding and even newer to Octave and I'm aware that it's an extremely simple, basic question - foolish, even. But even so, if someone could please tell me how to code this, I'd be glad.

```
function value = sqrmat (x)
  % returns true if x is a square matrix and false otherwise
  if rows(x)==columns(x)
    value=true;
  else
    value=false;
  endif
end
```

Comment: I suggest you re-read the chapter in the documentation about defining functions, paying special attention to how the return values are defined: https://docs.octave.org/latest/Defining-Functions.html

Comment: Also read the documentation on `return`, you'll see it doesn't take any arguments: https://docs.octave.org/latest/Returning-from-a-Function.html#index-return

Comment: the syntax problem is gone, yes, but x still undefined

Comment: How are you calling the function? You are supposed to pass a value as input, which will be bound to `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Octave has "script files" and "function files". To create a "script file", use a command (or statement) that has no effect.

Put this command at the top of the file, before all defined functions. Examples:

**Declare any number...**
In this case, the program assigns this number to the variable "ans".

```
% script
1;

function value = sqrmat (x)
  % returns true if x is a square matrix and false otherwise
  if rows(x)==columns(x)
    value=true;
  else
    value=false;
  endif
end
```

**A simple message...**
It could be a notification, a greeting, and so on.

```
% script
printf("File accessed\n")
```